# Matplotllib plot scatter with circle sizes proportional from distance to mean

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I would like to plot a scatter of values distances from mean in a scatter plot.

Here is my code for this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[5,6,2,6,9]
y=[2,4,5,1,10]
x_mean=np.mean(x)
y_mean=np.mean(y)
x_dist_mean=x-x_mean
y_dist_mean=y-y_mean

my labels=['horse', 'cat' , 'dog', 'fish', 'ape']
plt.scatter(x_dist_mean, y_dist_mean ,alpha=0.5 )
plt.show()
```

However, I would like to have the dots in the scatter proportional in size for the distance from mean, so a large distance would give a big circle and a small distance would give a small circle. In addition I would also like to color the circles with the label names in my_labels.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in the `s` parameter for the sizes of the dots and later annotate the dots. You can play with the [annotate](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate) function a lot more. (I just placed the labels to start at the center of the dot, but you can make it look different...)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[5,6,2,6,9]
y=[2,4,5,1,10]
x_mean = np.mean(x)
y_mean = np.mean(y)
x_dist_mean = x - x_mean
y_dist_mean = y - y_mean

size = np.abs(x_dist_mean * y_dist_mean) * 100
labels=['horse', 'cat' , 'dog', 'fish', 'ape']

plt.scatter(x_dist_mean, y_dist_mean, s=size, alpha=0.5, label=labels)
for label, x, y in zip(labels, x_dist_mean, y_dist_mean):
    plt.annotate(label, xy = (x, y))
```

Comment: Great!!!, do you also have some ide of how to color the circles diffrentley for each label name?

Comment: @jonas Yes, pass a list of colors as the `c` parameter to the `scatter` function. [Docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) and [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo2.html).